# Laravel создать запись в базе

Tags: laravel

Как создать запись в Laravel используя `Facades\DB` ?

Comment: `DB::table('users')->insert( ['name' => 'john', 'email' => 'email@me.dd'] );`

Answer (score 1):

```
\DB::table('my_table')->insert([
  'col1' => 'val1',
  'col2' => 'val2'
]);
```